# Resizing image bound to datasource with an IValueConverter

Tags: c#, data-binding, winrt-xaml, ivalueconverter

I have an image file bound to an Image element inside of a Grid as follows

```
   <FlipView x:Name="FlipView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsViewSource}}" SelectionChanged="FlipView_SelectionChanged">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged">
                    <Image Source="{Binding File, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Stretch="None" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

The Image is set to not stretch because I am doing the resizing inside of the  IValueConverter so that small images do not get pixelated and while large images are still shrunk to fit the screen.

When the size of my app changes, how can I trigger the IValueConverter to recalculate the size of the Image that is currently displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, when the size of your app changes, set the File property value.

```
public PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
     PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null)
     {
          var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
          handler(this, e);
     }
}

private String file;

public String File
{
    get 
    { 
         return file; 
    }
    set
    {
         file = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("File");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. What would I use to handle the PropertyChangedEvent?

Comment: it is part of the Data Binding framework which will handle it

Comment: That worked. I also had to set the UpdateSource on my binding to PropertyChanged.

Comment: Yes, that's true, you need to update the data source.